# Create Xpath using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/list/strona/1/sta/2,3,9']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
        }


    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//td[@class='icon_link']//a//@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)

  

    def parse_book(self, response):
        wev={}
        d1=response.xpath("//*[@class='line_list_K']//div//span")
        for i in range(len(d1)):
            if 'Status:' in d1[i].get():
                d2=response.xpath("//div["+str(i+1)+"]//text()").get()
                print(d2)
```

I will get the `status` value but they will give me empty output this is page link https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/abramska-danuta-51494

[image]

Comment: I have add text() in d2 xpath

Comment: this is page link https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/adamiak-aleksandra-34398

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not selecting your element more specific by its `text` and getting the text from its next sibling:

```
//span[text()[contains(.,'Status')]]/following-sibling::div/text()
```

Example: http://xpather.com/ZUWI58a4

To get the email:

```
//span[text()[contains(.,'Email')]]/following-sibling::div/(concat(@data-ea,'@',@data-eb))
```

Comment: I would have never thought of that.  +1

Comment: how can I Create xpath for `email`

Comment: how create xpath for email

Comment: this is page link https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/adamiak-aleksandra-34398

Comment: This would be predestined for [asking a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) with exact this focus - Same pattern, but you have to get the attributes of the element instead of its text

Comment: create new question for email https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72813761/giving-invalid-expression-error-for-xpath

Answer (score 0):

Your `d2` xpath isn't targeting the correct `div`.

This should work:

```
def parse_book(self, response):
    wev = {}  # <- this is never used
    for child in response.xpath('//div[@class="line_list_K"]/*'):
       if 'Status:' child.xpath(".//span/text()").get():
           d2 = child.xpath(".//div/text()").get()
           print(d2)
```