# Giving invalid expression error for Xpath

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

It will give me the invalid path expression and I am trying to scrape email https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/abaewicz-dominik-49965

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/list/strona/1/sta/2,3,9']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
        }


    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//td[@class='icon_link']//a//@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)

  

    def parse_book(self, response):
        
        data=response.xpath("//span[text()[contains(.,'Email')]]/following-sibling::div/(concat(@data-ea,'@',@data-eb)")
        
       
        
        yield{
            'email':data
           
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, your xpath is wrong:

```py
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess


class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    start_urls = ['https://rejestradwokatow.pl/adwokat/list/strona/1/sta/2,3,9']
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 1,
        'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.130 Safari/537.36'
    }

    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//td[@class='icon_link']//a//@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)

    def parse_book(self, response):
        data = response.xpath("concat(//span[text()[contains(.,'Email')]]/following-sibling::div/@data-ea, '@',//span[text()[contains(.,'Email')]]/following-sibling::div/@data-eb)").get()
        if data == '@':
            data = 'No Email Address'
        yield {
            'email': data
        }
```

(BTW you can get it without concat if you want to)

Comment: in every line they give `no emai address`

Comment: they do not give any email

Comment: they give you any email

Comment: It does return the email address, if the page contains the email address with the xpath you provided. What's not working for you?

Comment: not provide any email just print `no emai address`

Comment: `d3=response.xpath("//span[text()[contains(.,'Data skreślenia z listy:')]]/following-sibling::div/text()").get()